# SQL Security - creating a secure SQL command

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-injection

I am wondering how best to ensure that security in Oracle databases can be assured.

Comment: Use the query parameterization features of whatever tool/technology you are using within your application to talk to Oracle ... (which you have not mentioned)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Also: which programming language are you using?

Comment: The DBMS is Oracle.  It's in the prose.  On that same theme, what is the programming language for the application?

Comment: If I were you, I'd create a stored procedure (possibly in a package) that took the student id as an in parameter and returned a ref cursor as an out parameter. Then your query would be along the lines of `select ... from proj_details where student = in_student_id;`, which means it would be using a bind variable and thus immune to SQL injection. Your application would then just need to call the procedure and process the resultant ref cursor. If you absolutely must avoid stored procedures, do make sure you bind the variable into your sql query, rather than doing string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
SELECT TITLE, SUPERVISOR FROM PROJ_DETAILS WHERE STUDENT =
DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(' The name entered and stored in username')
```

OR

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT TITLE, SUPERVISOR FROM PROJ_DETAILS WHERE STUDENT = 
:1 ' USING vstudent;
```

Comment: This makes sense. If I didn't implement any of your suggestions and instead, If user passwords were also stored in the database, and the user entered a password as well as a username with the querystring built to test for both in the WHERE clause, would SQL injection attacks be prevented?

Comment: @BitLord Never store passwords in a database.  Instead store the password hashes.  Use a prebuilt solution if possible.  If you must do it yourself, choose a good hash algorithm (not MD5), salt, and repeat multiple times.